# Странное поведение float в цикле for

Tags: c#, float

В программе нужно было многократно добавлять значение переменной типа float, для чего написал цикл:

```
float high = 100.0f, step = 3.59f;
for (float i = step; i < high; i += step)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

И на выходе почему-то получил следующее:

```
3,59
7,18
10,77
14,36
17,95
21,54
25,13
28,72
32,31
35,9
39,49
43,08
46,67
50,26
53,85
57,44
61,03
64,62
68,20999
71,79999
75,38998
78,97998
82,56998
86,15997
89,74997
93,33997
96,92996
```

Я слышал, что в javascript из-за округления может получиться так, что 0.1 +0.2 == 0.30000000000000004, но в C# такое встречаю впервые. Чем это вызвано?

Comment: Эти причины не зависят от языка

Comment: Используете функции округления

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вычисления с плавающей запятой работают с погрешностью на любом языке.

Возникновение погрешностей связано с тем, что числа представляются в виде дробей со знаменателем 2. Некоторые числа в таком виде конечной дробью записать нельзя, отсюда - погрешность.